# Metamask doesn't connect to it's own localhost or hardhat localhost

Tags: solidity, blockchain, metamask, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Metamask doesn't connect to it's own localhost. I run a hardhat node from Mac. I know it's a known issue, but I've tried all available methods listed below.
[image]

1. I tried installing older versions of Metamask (initially 10.14.3)
2. Tried adding other networks like Hardhat's 31337 . But it's a known Metamask bug
   [image: List item]
3. Tried editing Metamask default localhost, but it throws error at it's default chain ID lol
   [image]
4. Tried setting Hardhat chain ID to 1337

Comment: What client are you running on localhost? Geth, ganache, besu, etc. Are you connecting from windows, linux, mac?

Comment: @Ismael I'm running a hardhat localhost network from mac

Comment: Are you sure it is running at the configure port? Perhaps you might be affected by this https://hardhat.org/metamask-issue.html.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to pass the `chainId:1337` directly in the `hardhat.config.js` file.

e.g

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

// The next line is part of the sample project, you don't need it in your
// project. It imports a Hardhat task definition, that can be used for
// testing the frontend.
require("./tasks/faucet");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337 // We set 1337 to make interacting with MetaMask simpler
    }
  }
};
```